# False data in customList in a dynamically created fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I have an `Activity` with 2 fragments.
Declared a `ParentTabFragment` in my `Activity` in which there is a `TabLayout` and a `ViewPager`.

There's a method in my `ParentTabFragment` called `addPage` which gets called in the `Activity`.

The `addPage` has another method called `addFrag` which is called from a `ViewPagerAdapter` creating the `views` in the `ChildTabFragment` dynamically.

There is a `for loop` which runs in the `Activity`, so the `Fragments` are created according to the number of items in the `customList`, creating the amount of `tabs` and pages in the `Fragments`.

In my `ChildTabFragment` I load a `customList` on `tab` selection `event`,
when I select a `Tab` in the `ParentTabFragment`, I call a `getTabID()` method from the `ChildTabFragment` and send the id of the `Tab` due to which I load the `customList` according to the id in the `ParentTabFragment`.

Problem is when I swipe or select tabs, duplicate/false data gets created in the `customList`.

I get the proper `Id` of the selected tab but when I try to pass it in the method, random id is called.

In my Activity Class:

```
for (int j =0;j<it.size();j++){
            parentTabFragment.addPage(it.get(j).getTabMenuItem(), it.get(j).getTabMenuId() , selectedMenu);
        }
```

ParentTabFragment:

```
public void addPage(String pagename, String pageId, String selectedMenu) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("data", pagename);
        //bundle.putString("pageID", pageId);
        childTabFragment = new ChildTabFragment();
        childTabFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        adapter.addFrag(childTabFragment, pagename, pageId);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        if (selectedMenu == null) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
                if (tabLayout.getTabAt(i).getText().equals(selectedMenu)) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            }
        }
        if (adapter.getCount() > 0) tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabLayout();
    }

    public void setupTabLayout() {
        selectedTabPosition = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(adapter.getTabView(i));
        }
    }
```

ChildTabFragment:

```
public class ChildTabFragment extends Fragment {
    String childname;
    int menuItemId;
    TextView textViewChildName, txtViewItemId;
    ListView childTabMenuList;

    private ArrayList<ChildTabMenu_POJO> childTabMenuPojoList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView listView;
    private ChildTabMenuAdapter childTabMenuAdapter;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_tab_fragment, container, false);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        childname = bundle.getString("data");
        getIDs(view); 
        return view;
    }

    private void getIDs(View view) { 
        childTabMenuList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.childTabMenuList); 
        loadChildMenu();
    }

    private void loadChildMenu(menuItemId) { 

        ChildTabMenu_POJO menu_pojo4 = new ChildTabMenu_POJO(String.valueOf(menuItemId), "4");  
        childTabMenuPojoList.add(menu_pojo4);
        childTabMenuAdapter = new ChildTabMenuAdapter(childTabMenuPojoList, getActivity());
        childTabMenuList.setAdapter(childTabMenuAdapter);

    }

    public void getTabID(int tabId) {
        menuItemId = tabId; 
        Log.e("updatefrag", String.valueOf(menuItemId)); 
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<Adapter_POJO> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    Adapter_POJO adapter_pojo;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, Context context, ViewPager viewPager,
                            TabLayout tabLayout) {
        super(manager);
        this.context = context;
        this.viewPager = viewPager;
        this.tabLayout = tabLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }


    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFragmentTitleList.size();
    }



    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title, String pageId) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        adapter_pojo = new Adapter_POJO(title,pageId);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(adapter_pojo);
    }

    public View getTabView(final int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_pager_adapter_layout, null);
        TextView tabItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTabItemName);
        tabItemName.setText(mFragmentTitleList.get(position).adapterMenuItem);
        tabItemName.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));

        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position).adapterMenuItem;
    }
    public String getPageId(int position){

        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position).adapterMenuId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question so you need to create newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments

```
public static ChildTabFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
        FirstFragment fragmentFirst = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", page);
        args.putString("someTitle", title);
        fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentFirst;
    }
```

And Store instance variables based on arguments passed in your ChildTabFragment .

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
        title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
    }
```

And now update the view in your `onCreateView` method

```
TextView tvLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLabel);
        tvLabel.setText(page + " -- " + title);
```

And the main thing you should returns the `ChildTabFragment` to display for that page from your `ViewPagerAdapter` like this.

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ChildTabFragment.newInstance(position,"page "+String.valueOf(position));
    }
```